# Laravel Queue, Jobs, Redis - falling back to sync connection

Tags: laravel, redis, jobs

i'm using Laravel 5.4, i'm trying to set a queued job. 
Here is my config:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

and my config/queue.php

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],

    'emails' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'emails',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
```

Here is my code

```
 public function handle()
 {
    dd($this->job->getConnectionName());
 }
```

My problem, when i change sync the QUEUE_DRIVER, i get "sync"
But when i change redis , i get any thing.

Comment: Have you started the queue listener? `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: also ensure you restart your queue after changing any env variables `php artisan queue:restart`